# How set nodejs redis persistence config?

Tags: node.js, node-redis

I am using node redis.
I want to change the persistence config of redis.
I want to set it to AOF(Append Only File).
How to do that in node js after creating the redisClient ?

```
const redisclient = redis.createClient();
... (What else ) ...
```

How to set the persistence config?

I googled, i don't find any suitable doc for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [CONFIG SET](https://redis.io/commands/config-set), which has a small blurb that mentions:

> It is possible to switch persistence from RDB snapshotting to
> append-only file (and the other way around) using the CONFIG SET
> command. For more information about how to do that please check the
> [persistence page](https://redis.io/topics/persistence).

The linked persistence page says that:

> You can turn on the AOF in your configuration file:
>
> appendonly yes

The [nodejs redis library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) implements a 1-to-1 mapping of the redis commands, so there is a config method on the client object that you can use like:

```
client.config("SET", "appendonly", "yes");
```

Comment: That looks good to me @Rehum (assuming you use the same variable name for `client` and `redisclient`). I believe the client library will automatically queue up those commands and send them when the connection is established, so I suspect it's all good. You can use `config get *` from the redis-cli to check that the setting has taken hold.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's what i am looking for.   These links help me so much:  [ConfigSet ](https://redis.io/commands/config-set )     -    [Persistence-demystified ](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html ) 
[Peristence ](https://redis.io/topics/persistence )       -   So I have finally 
`const redisclient = redis.createClient();
redisclient .config("SET", "appendonly", "yes");
redisclient .config("SET", "appendfsync", "everysec");
`
Is that right ?

Comment: Ok. Thanks Dear